# Move certain section information above another section in a configuration file

Tags: bash, unix

I have a requirement to move all the sections and its values present below [mysqld] to above it in a mysql configuration file and after moving those contents they need to be deleted,I have tried the below script but it is just adding variable name instead of the contents and deletes the contents,Can anyone help resolve it or it would be appreciated if i get code to automatically move the sections and its content present below [mysqld] to the top of [mysqld] section

output:

```
[client]
a=99

${value}
[mysqld]
b=1
c=2
```

script:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME='my.cnf'
LINE_NUMBER1=$1
LINE_NUMBER2=$2
declare -a LINE_CONTENT=$(sed -n "${LINE_NUMBER1},${LINE_NUMBER2}"p "$FILENAME")
sed -i "${LINE_NUMBER1},${LINE_NUMBER2}"'d' "$FILENAME"
for value in "${LINE_CONTENT[@]}"; do
sed -i "/^#/n;/\[mysqld]/i \${value}" "$FILENAME"
done
```

Current file:my.cnf

```
[client]
a=99

[mysqld]
b=1
c=2

[myisamchk]
a=1,2
d=22
e=name

[sst]
f=yes
```

Expected after script execution

```
[client]
a=99

[myisamchk]
a=1,2
d=22
e=name

[sst]
f=yes

[mysqld]
b=1
c=2
```

Actual my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
disable-log-bin = 1
----GAPS----
skip-name-resolve = 1
performance-schema = 0
local-infile = 0
mysqlx = 0
open_files_limit = 200000
max_allowed_packet = 256M
sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
-----GAPS------
innodb_dedicated_server = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 48


[myisamck]
a=3
b=4
```

result is:

only the below is being copied below [myisamchk] if there are gaps,if there are no gaps then it works fine:

```
[mysqld]
disable-log-bin = 1
```

Comment: I do not see a difference between *current file* and *Expected after script execution* except the order

Comment: @Jens That is the requirement,the sections below [mysqld] should be moved to above [mysqld].

Comment: In other words, the mysqld section should be moved so it's the last one?

Comment: @Shawn All the sections present below [mysqld] should be moved above it and after that [mysqld] will be the last in the file.

Comment: What is the difference between `Actual` and `current` `my.cnf` ? Also that `-----GAPS------` is a literal string or a blank/empty line? Because if it is literal then Shawn's answer works just fine.

Comment: @Jetchisel  --GAPS-- is a blank line.

Comment: `printf '%s\n' '/^\[mysqld\]$/kx' "'x;/^\[.*/-1m$" "'x-1a" "" . ,p Q | ed -s my.cnf`

Comment: @Jetchisel This is working!Can you just brief me a bit about it and the mistake in the below code  i mentioned in the question so that i will make a note:                                                               #!/bin/bash
FILENAME='my.cnf'
LINE_NUMBER1=$1
LINE_NUMBER2=$2
declare -a LINE_CONTENT=$(sed -n "${LINE_NUMBER1},${LINE_NUMBER2}"p "$FILENAME")
sed -i "${LINE_NUMBER1},${LINE_NUMBER2}"'d' "$FILENAME"
for value in "${LINE_CONTENT[@]}"; do
sed -i "/^#/n;/\[mysqld]/i \${value}" "$FILENAME"
done

Comment: `kx` the `k` is the command to mark and `x` is the marker, expanding the marker `x` prefix it with a single quote `'`  See  https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/ed.html  and https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html , for the `sed`  you're looping through the lines and running `sed` line-by-line and `LINE_CONTENT` is NOT an array, it is a [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) being assigned in a variable. Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for recommendation/validation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ed` to the rescue:

```bash
ed -s my.cnf <<'EOF'
/^\[mysqld\]$/;/^$/m$
?\[mysqld\]?i

.
w
EOF
```

First find the block starting with the line `[mysqld]` and ending with the next blank line, **m**ove it to the end of the file, and make sure to **i**nsert a blank line before it so it doesn't blend into the previous final block, then **w**rite the changed file back out.

Comment: it is just moving only  [mysqld] section but not its contents,Can you please review.

Comment: @Raj Works for me with the sample file you gave.

Comment: You are right,it is working for the sample i provided,But for the actual my.cnf it is working only if there are no gaps between the data in section [mysqld],if there are gaps in between the data it is only copying [mysqld],Can you suggest?

Comment: @Raj, then update your sample file and add what the `gap` that you're describing.

Comment: If your sample data isn't representative of the real thing, it's hard to help...

Comment: Edit your post/question and to reflect the `gap` in the sample file, not here in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a (somewhat lengthy) SED script that might do the job.

```
#! /bin/sh

MOVE_SECTION='mysqld'
AFTER_SECTION='sst'


SED_SCRIPT="$(cat <<-_EOF_
#n
/^\[/!{p;b}

/^\[${MOVE_SECTION}\]/{
  :hold
  H
  n
  /^\[/!b hold
  }

/^\[${AFTER_SECTION}/!{p;b}
:loop
p
\$b append
n
/^\[/!b loop
H

:append
x
p

_EOF_
)"

sed -e "$SED_SCRIPT" INPUTFILE
```

Given the following input:

```
[client]

a=99

b=101


[mysqld]
blah=this

b=1

c=2


[myisamchk]

a=1,2

d=22

e=name

[sst]

f=yes
this=that

[other]
blah=1

blih=2

bloh=3
```

... it should produce:

```
[client]

a=99

b=101


[myisamchk]

a=1,2

d=22

e=name

[sst]

f=yes
this=that


[mysqld]
blah=this

b=1

c=2


[other]
blah=1

blih=2

bloh=3
```

Let me know if it needs adjustments.

HTH

##### *Edit*:

Removed "foundSection" loop (unneeded).