# Move contents of one section above another section in a configuration file

Tags: bash, unix, ed

I have a requirement to move [mysqld] section in a mysql configuration file above another section named `#SAFE#` in a mysql configuration file and after the section is moved there should be space between the sections,Please find the below code and requirement:

code used:

```
#!/bin/bash
for server in `cat /home/servers.txt'`
username=$1
password=$2
do
sshpass-p $PWD ssh -o stricthostchecking=no $USERNAME@$server "ed -s /home/my.cnf <<'EOF'
/^\[mysqld\]$/;/^\[.*/ -1m$
?\[mysqld\]?i

.
w
EOF"
done
```

Actual my.cnf:

```
   [client]
   a=2
   b=7
   
   [mysql]
    d=6
    e=7
 
   [mysqld]
    
    disable-log-bin = 1
    
    skip-name-resolve = 1
    performance-schema = 0
    local-infile = 0
    mysqlx = 0
    open_files_limit = 200000
    max_allowed_packet = 256M
    sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

    #the below are password related of [mysqld]
     validate password=1
    
    innodb_dedicated_server = 1
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 48
    
    [myisamck]
    a=3
    b=4
    
    [sst]
    d=3
    c=4
    
    # SAFE #
    d=0
    f=0
```

Requirement:

The `[mysqld]` section and its sections should be pasted above `# SAFE #(` section in very        few cases section is given as `##SAFE##` or `#SAFE#` or `# SAFE #` in few of the my.cnf files),Please support.

Expected output:

```
  [client]
   a=2
   b=7
   
   [mysql]
    d=6
    e=7
    
    [myisamck]
    a=3
    b=4
    
    [sst]
    d=3
    c=4
    
   [mysqld]
    
    disable-log-bin = 1
    
    skip-name-resolve = 1
    performance-schema = 0
    local-infile = 0
    mysqlx = 0
    open_files_limit = 200000
    max_allowed_packet = 256M
    sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
    
    #the below are password related of [mysqld]
     validate password=1

    innodb_dedicated_server = 1
    innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 48
    
    # SAFE #
    d=0
    f=0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move certain section information above another section in a configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76748132/move-certain-section-information-above-another-section-in-a-configuration-file)

Comment: @Jens As per my requirement i need to move it above a specific section.

Comment: will the `[mysqld]` block *always* come before the `# SAFE #` line?

Comment: Look for INI file parsers, but you'll need to do some coding.

Comment: @markp-fuso yes,it has to be moved before # SAFE # always.

Comment: I'm not asking about where to *move* the `[mysqld]` block, I'm asking about where the `[mysqld]` block appears in the source file, *before* the move must take place

Comment: @markp-fuso it usually appears after [client] and [mysql] sections.

Comment: my question was: *before the move* .... does the `[mysqld]` block ***always*** come before the `# SAFE #` line?

Comment: @markp-fuso No,It does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use `sshpass` but plain ol `ssh` with key, something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

servers=(
  server1
  server2
  server3
  ...
)

for server in "${servers[@]}"; do
  ssh -t "jetchisel@$server" 'ed -s ~/my.cnf <<EOF
  /#*[[:space:]]*SAFE[[:space:]]*#*/kx
  /^\[mysqld\]$/;/^\[.*/-1m'\''x-1
  ,p
  Q
EOF'
done
```

---

To add the content of `/home/servers.txt` to an array, one way is to use `mapfile` aka `readarray` which is a bash4+ feature.

```
mapfile -t servers < /home/servers.txt
```

---

- Add `w` after the line where `,p` is at to actually write/edit the file in-place
- Remove the `,p` to silence the output.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
   username=$1
   PWD=$2
  mapfile -t servers < /home/servers.txt
  for server in "${servers[@]}"; do
  sshpass-p $PWD ssh -o stricthostchecking=no $USERNAME@$server 'ed -s ~/my.cnf <<EOF
  /#*[[:space:]]*SAFE[[:space:]]*#*/kx
  /^\[mysqld\]$/;/^\[.*/-1m'\''x-1
  w
  Q
EOF'
done                                                                                                                                       @Jetchisel Tried but it is not saving in the file or ,p is not printing the info.

Comment: I did iinstall sshpass, and it works as expected, so I don't know what is wrong with your setup.

Comment: Iam getting ? as the output

Comment: Well, to start with the `stricthostchecking=no` is an error on my side, it should be `StrictHostKeyChecking=no ` ...

Comment: Also, a heredoc requires to have a literal new lines, not in one-line like what you have.

Comment: There was a problem with my setup,It is working now.

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions/Understandings:

- input lines may have leading white space (based on OP's sample `my.cnf` file)
- the `[mysqld]` block may come before or after the `# SAFE #` line; options include storing the entire file in memory structures or making two passes through the file
- OP has mentioned both `#SAFE#` and `# SAFE #` so we'll look for a line with the 3 strings `#` / `SAFE` / `#` where they may be white space between the strings
- the line `# SAFE #` (with or without white space) only occurs once in the file

One `awk` idea requiring two passes through the input file:

```
awk '
BEGIN { regex_hdr  = "^[[:space:]]*" "[[]" "[^]]*"        "[]]"                     "[[:space:]]*$"
        regex_safe = "^[[:space:]]*" "#"   "[[:space:]]*" "SAFE" "[[:space:]]*" "#" "[[:space:]]*$"
      }

      { if ($0 ~ regex_hdr) {               # if line looks like "[....]" then ...
           if ($1 == "[mysqld]") {          # if the header is "[mysqld]" then ...
              if   (FNR==NR) save = 1       # if 1st file set the "save" flag else ...
              else           skip = 1       # (2nd file) set the "skip" flag
           }
           else
              save = skip = 0               # (not "[mysqld]") then clear flags
        }

        if ($0 ~ regex_safe) {              # if line looks like "# SAFE #" and ...
           if (NR>FNR)                      # if processing 2nd file then ...
              for (i=1; i<=blkcnt; i++)     # loop through the block[] array and ...
                  print block[i]            # print the "[mysqld]" block
           save = skip = 0                  # reset variables
        }

        if (save)                           # if 1st file and in the "[mysqld]" block then ...
           block[++blkcnt] = $0             # save the line in our block[] array
        if ( NR>FNR && !skip )              # if 2nd file and not skipping then ...
           print                            # print current line
      }
' my.cnf my.cnf                             # two copies of file are read/processed
```

Where:

- the regex's are broken into smaller strings for easier reading/understanding (`awk` will concatenate them into a single string during processing)
- `FNR==NR` - is true when processing the 1st file
- `NR>FNR` - is true when processing the 2nd file
- during processing of the 1st file we find and save (in the `block[]` array) the `[mysqld]` block
- during processing of the 2nd file we *a)* ignore all lines in the `[mysqld]` block, *b)* print all other lines to stdout except *c)* if the line consists of the string `# SAFE #` then we'll first print the contents of the `block[]` array (ie, the `[mysqld]` block) to stdout and then print the `# SAFE #` line to stdout

This generates:

```
[client]
a=2
b=7

[mysql]
 d=6
 e=7

 [myisamck]
 a=3
 b=4

 [sst]
 d=3
 c=4

[mysqld]

 disable-log-bin = 1

 skip-name-resolve = 1
 performance-schema = 0
 local-infile = 0
 mysqlx = 0
 open_files_limit = 200000
 max_allowed_packet = 256M
 sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

 #the below are password related of [mysqld]
  validate password=1

 innodb_dedicated_server = 1
 innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 48

 # SAFE #
 d=0
 f=0
```

**NOTES:**

- once OP is satisifed with the output, and assuming the intention is to overwrite the original file, then *a)* redirect the output to a temporary file (eg, `awk '...' my.cnf my.cnf > tmpfile`) and then *b)* `mv tmpfile my.cnf`
- if using a newer version `GNU awk` it is possible to have `awk` overwrite the original file but that will require playing with the `inplace` library and toggling some related variables on the command line ... doable but a bit more complicated
- if getting this to work in a `ssh/EOF` construct is too wieldly, perhaps consider copying the file to the remove host (eg, `scp`) before executing (via `ssh`) ... ?

Comment: Your answer is also working,Thanks for for your efforts for writing such a complicated code.Iam not able to mark two correct answers.

Comment: @Raj in our earlier exchange of questions/comments you confirmed that, *before* performing the edit, the `[mysqld]` block could come before *or* after the `# SAFE #`; the answer you've accepted does not appear to work if, *before* performing the edit, the `[mysqld]` comes after the `# SAFE #`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '
   /\[mysqld\]/,/\[myisamck\]/{ 
       if($0 !~ / *\[myisamck\] */) {
          section=section"\n"$0
          next
       } 
   }
   /#?# ?SAFE ?##?/{
       print section
   }1
' my.cnf
```